# Python openpyxl excel formula altering values in top row of excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have formula for certain columns in excel. Each time program runs, it has to calculate formula based on values present in other columns.
when program run 1st time, its working fine.
When I run the program 2nd time and so on, it is altering the formula values on current row -1.
Not sure why it is changing values on row above the current one.
what do I have to do to stop altering values in above row each time program runs?

Below is my code and screen shot. Values in code are data derived from web scraping

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path = r"C:\Users\file.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb[sheet_name]
row = sheet.max_row + 1
sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=Date)  # => column A
sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=Time)   # => column C
sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value=PCTCLOSE)  # => column F
sheet.cell(row=row, column=4, value=RTValidResponse)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=7, value=RTCLOSE)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=10, value=RTValidResponse)

sheet.cell(row=row, column=6, value=f'=SUM(D{row + 1}-D{row})')
sheet.cell(row=row, column=9, value=f'=SUM(G{row + 1}-G{row})')
sheet.cell(row=row, column=11, value=f'=SUM(J{row + 1}-J{row})')
sheet.cell(row=row, column=12, value=f'=SUM(I{row}/K{row})')
```

excel from 1st run which is working as expected

[image]

excel from 2nd run where you see column f, k values are altered in row 2

[image]

Comment: `max_row` will change when you add cells so your code should account for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not altering the formulas: your formula in `F2` for instance ends up being `SUM(D3-D2)` (which is a bit strange, btw). So until `D3` is empty it has a certain value, but as soon as you populate `D3` the value in `F2` gets recalculated

Comment: formula is correct and that's what I need. How can I stop recalculating?

Comment: Excel has an option to set recalculation to Manual or Auto if you want, although I don't understand how it could be useful to you - sooner or later you will launch (manual) recalc and the values will then change, otherwise there's no point in having formulas. Regarding the formula I said it's a bit strange because the `SUM` function is redundant here